# different in final,static,final static

Tags: java, android

I write constant just use in one class in Android.
Is it good to write like `private final static String str = "xx"`,`private final String str ="xx";`or `private static String str ="xx"`? I have known the difference between `final` and `static`.

Comment: Well none of these are valid, you did not give any variable name. It would not compile. But constands should be declared `static final`. Make it public if the constand is to be used elsewhere, else private if it should only be visible for the class where it is declared.

Answer (score 1):

Using `static` means that a variable or method will belong to the class itself, as opposed to an instance of the class.

Using `final` makes it so that the variable or method cannot be changed.

Using `static final` in a constant variable means that it will be accessible without requiring an instance, and that it is a constant (cannot be changed, through the `final` keyword).

This being said, you should use `public static final` or `private static final`.

Comment: I only use it in one class.so i want to know it is necessary to set it static

Comment: and  i set the class Singleton

Comment: It's definitely not necessary, unless you have some static methods that need to use the field.

Comment: I mean the static var will in the memory.In my case,final is better than final static?

Answer (score 0):

Constants are better to declare as `private static final` or `public static final` depending on the visibility that you need.

If the constant is not `static` then it's stored in every class instance. 
If it's not `final` than it's not a constant. :)
And the visibility modifier may vary.

Example of a constant declaration:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "username";
```

Comment: if i set the class Singleton. is it necessary to set static

Answer (score 0):

A **static** fields is shared across all instances and the class itself. It belongs to the class.

A **final** field is something which cannot be changed once initialized.

So, you should declare it as `private static final String x = "xx"`.

And when a `static final` field is primitive or string type, the compiler would replace them with all occurrences at compiler time giving performance gains.

Answer (score 0):

As you might be knowing

> > You can't change the value of a variable declared with final after initialization.
> >     Static variables are class variables, not instance variable. That means change in their values by any instance variable is not limited to just the changing instance variable.

**final static variables are constants**. If you understand these two final and static well, then you will realize it.
When you are declaring a constant, it makes sense to declare them public. So that any one can use them and they don't have to declare them anywhere else.

Now its better to use **Enum**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a constance,you should do it like this "private static final String varaiablename = "xxx";".
static means the variable will be init before you new any objects of the Class.
final means no one could change the varialbe after it been evaluate.
so if you want to declare a constant variable ,you should use the key words "final" and "static"